# Android 7.1.2 text relocations error

Tags: android, runtime-error

[image]

just started testing my app on android 7 and up and  got this error msg, That i have no idea what's is talking about i click ok  then i just get a black screen and nothing happen any idea about

**UPDATE**

it seems the problem is in compiled version used by "NDk", i did not used any ndk by my self but i used a lib to compress the videos and it's seems that this lib is compiled with older version of ndk THE QUESTION NOW is how to update this lib compiled version

> NOTE : I'M USING VIRTUALBOX

Comment: any ideas guys & girls ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the virtual machine  it uses intel x86 and the NDK is  compiled in ARM architecture.